# code to get number of unread emails in BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I need to code that returns how many unread emails are in the inbox on a BlackBerry.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Store store = Session.getDefaultInstance().getStore(); 
int numUnread = store.getUnreadMessageCount();
```